# How to detect non-system-variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, detect

How do I detect all children of 'window' that are defined by the user?

I want to detect `window.test`, but I don't want to get `window.Math`.
Is there a way to list those Variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your question is interesting but does not show any research effort. I suggest you to add a bit more information. It may be useful for further readers who face the same problem...*

---

When you load a web page, you get a fresh new `window` object. So if you want to detect custom properties, it is a good idea to store the initial state of `window` at the top level of your code. It will allow you later to retrieve the new properties using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` or `Object.keys()`.

### Object.getOwnPropertyNames()

```js
var customKeys,
    // We save the initial length of the array containing window properties
    nbProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).length;
 
    // Custom properties
    window.foo = 'Foo';
    window.bar = 'Bar';

    // We get the latest properties that were internally pushed to the array
    customKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).slice(nbProps);
    
    console.log(customKeys);
```

### Object.keys()

```js
var customKeys,
    // We save the initial length of the array containing window properties
    nbProps = Object.keys(window).length;
 
    // Custom properties
    window.foo = 'Foo';
    window.bar = 'Bar';

    // We get the latest properties that were internally pushed to the array
    customKeys = Object.keys(window).slice(nbProps);
    
    console.log(customKeys);
```

### Object.getOwnPropertyNames() vs Object.keys()

The difference between `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` and `Object.keys()` is **enumerability**. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` takes into account all properties of an object, including non-enumerable ones, whereas `Object.keys()` only takes into account enumerable properties.

Look at the following code:

```js
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)');
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).length + ' properties');
console.log('Math? ' + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).includes('Math'));

console.log('Object.keys(window)');
console.log(Object.keys(window).length + ' properties');
console.log('Math? ' + Object.keys(window).includes('Math'));
```